# Spring boot webapp as client of Google Oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, google-calendar-api, spring-security-oauth2

I'm writing a webapp using Spring Boot. For my project, I need to connect to Google for retrieving calendar information about users. 
So, I integrate Spring security Oauth2 for user connection and after I want to use the Google calendar API.

The connection is ok and after it, Google redirects to a page of my webapp defined by this controller:

```
@Controller
class ConnectedController {
    private String token

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    String welcome(Principal principal,
                   Model model) {
        OAuth2Authentication auth = principal
        model.addAttribute("user", auth.userAuthentication.details)

        // credential
        def api = new CalendarApi()
        token = auth.details.tokenValue
        println "Token: [$token]"
        api.fetch(token)
        return 'welcome'
    }
}
```

For the Calendar API, I need the access token value and the refresh token value. I find the access token value in the principal object but where is the refresh token?

For information, I configured the authorization like below to have the resfresh token (normally):

```
userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent
```

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret the [google Oauth2 doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#webserver) you get a authorization code when consent is given by the user. And this code should be used to get an access token and a refresh token from the API.

> The result is an authorization code, which the application can
>   exchange for an access token and a refresh token.

Have you tried [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code)?

Comment: I've read that but I don't find this authorization code (neither Authentification or Principal object). But I've well got the access token from the tokenValue of the details property of the Principal instance.

Comment: The doc sais that the authorization code will be passed as an queryparam in the redirect. Try adding `@RequestParam("code") String code` to your `@RequestMapping`
Also, be sure to set the grant type in your oauth properties. `security.oauth2.client.grant-type=authorization_code
`

Comment: That doesn't work. There is no "code" query parameter in the redirected URL :(

Comment: in case you use spring-boot, adding it like this in prop/yaml helped.. `userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline`